# data wont update in DB

Tags: php, mysqli

i am having trouble updating data to table in DB i looked to see if i had any errors but everything looks fine nothing is wrong with my previous code i already tested it using old code that uses $_POST i know that is not recommended that's why im trying this new code please help

```html
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "", "Password", "");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// escape variables for security

       $xskids = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['xskids']);
    $skids = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['skids']);

$sql="UPDATE shirt1_table SET xskids = '$xskids', skids = '$xskids' WHERE email = '$email'";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

OLD CODE

```html
<?php 
require_once("configur.php");
 
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "", "");
 
$query='UPDATE shirt1_table SET xskids="'.$_POST[xskids].'",skids="'.$_POST[skids].'"
WHERE email= "'.$_SESSION['email'].'"';

if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) {
 

  echo "success";

} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$mysqli->close();
    
?>
```

Comment: Does your database connection work?

Comment: yes it does but since this is new code i dont know if it affected it ill upload my old code

Comment: Did you check your php error log or does the code outputs any errors?

Comment: I don't get  any errors all I get is record added

Comment: You did not set `$email`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not set `$email` in your new code. Try to do it like this:

```
$xskids = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['xskids']);
$skids = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['skids']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_SESSION['email']);

$sql="UPDATE shirt1_table SET xskids = '$xskids', skids = '$xskids' WHERE email = '$email'";
```

Comment: thank you that works i thought it wasn't necessary since im not posting to table

Comment: @ghostbaby No problem